# How to play co-op with mutual streaming?

Tags: portal-2, magicka, streaming

Is it somehow possible to play a co-op game with a small overlay window showing someone else's screen while streaming the own screen content to them?

How can it be achieved, preferably with freeware?

Comment: Did you have a particular game in mind? Otherwise, I think you're asking on the wrong site...

Comment: @Raven you mean superuser? well, I'm specifically interested in Portal 2 and Magicka, but I'd really prefer one catches-all answer...

Comment: do you mean split-screen?

Comment: @Bora yes, kind of, but via LAN or internet connection when the game does not natively offer it

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Well, Portal 2 specifically already has that feature. Partner view, it's called -- bound to Tab by default, IIRC.

Comment: @lunboks good to know, thanks. something like that without being bound to a game would be great then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried simply using justin.tv or livestream and a built-in system like the steam or origin web browsers as overlays?  If you only need to view the other person's screen when stuck on a puzzle or something (a portal-like game, I suppose) this should be an easy to set up solution (though as was already mentioned, Portal 2 already has this functionality built in).

I know you would prefer a free solution, but I'll also take this opportunity to plug a dual-monitor computer setup.  Monitors can be had for around $100 if you wait for a deal.  Used CRT monitors can be had for cheap or free if you ask around.  You will never believe how much more productive you can be with dual monitors until you actually try it out.

Comment: Hey thanks, Dual Monitor might be a good idea - I know about the benefits due to the setup at work, that's a good point. Using the web overlay sounds great, but can it be setup to remain displayed while playing? But that brings me to another idea: If the PC is powerful enough, run the game and the screengrabber on a virtual PC while sticking a separate window of the stream on the real PC to foreground - Now if only both PCs _where_ powerful enough...

Comment: @TobiasKienzler That's the downside to my first suggestion - the steam and origin overlays take keyboard focus, so you can't continue playing the game while it's open.  It would work probably be fine on something like Portal 2 as I mentioned, but more time-sensitive games are probably straight out.

Comment: but it did point to the Virtual PC idea, so until something less resource-hogging shows up I'll accept your answer. Maybe something along the lines of a direct3d overlay (along [these lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741263/direct3d-hook-overlay)) might be able to show VLC playing a stream in foreground